# How to resize images in Ruby (Rails) without using RMagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, resize, rmagick

I need to load images from URL (stored in Amazon S3 bucket), create a thumbnail from this image and upload it (the new thumbnail) to the same S3 bucket.

Last 5 hours I am trying to install RMagick on my Lion OSX, but all my threads getting grey from RMagic. It seems to be impossible to install RMagick on OSX.

Thus, is there any other way to do it?

**EDIT:** 
In `Gemfile`:
gem "rmagick"

Error:

```
uninitialized constant ImagesController::Magick
```

In controller:

```
  def resize_images
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'RMagick'
    include Magick
    require "open-uri"

    file_url = open('URL to image')
    save_path = "/"

    f = File.new( File.join(save_path, file_url), "wb")
    f.write file_url.read 
    f.close

    image = Magick::Image.read(file_url).first
    image.change_geometry!("1500x150") { |cols, rows, img|
        newimg = img.resize(cols, rows)
        newimg.write("newfilename.jpg")
    }
  end
```

**EDIT2:**

When I put this into `Gemfile`:

```
gem "rmagick", :require => 'RMagick'
```

bundle it and run the server, I get following error:

```
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/mysql in PATH, mode 040777
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/mysql in PATH, mode 040777
/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require': cannot load such file -- RMagick (LoadError)
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/rubydev/looky/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I have RMagick installed on OSX so it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

[MiniMagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) and [ImageScience](https://github.com/seattlerb/image_science) are both fairly popular alternatives, I believe. That said, it is most certainly possible to install RMagick on OSX. Perhaps if you describe the error you're encountering, it can be corrected.